# WPF switch multiple control templates with DataType property fails

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate, controltemplate

I am trying to make a contactlist with 2 different types of contacts, FysiekContactPersoon (Fysical persons) and WinkelOfBedrijf (Corporates). They both are inherited from the class ContactPersoon.
my MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    ContactPersoonViewModel _viewmod = null;
    public ContactPersoonViewModel ViewMod
    {
        get { _viewmod ??= new ContactPersoonViewModel(); return _viewmod; }
        set => _viewmod = value;
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewMod.Import();
        DataContext = ViewMod;

    }

    private void InfoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogInfo dlg = new DialogInfo(ViewMod) { Owner = this };
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true) { }   
    }
}
```

When the user selects a contact from a datagrid on mainwindow and presses the Info button, the dialog window opens.I have created two templates that normally have to be applied each to its corresponding class.But the dialogwindow is empty, despite the fact that the current item is shown properly in the viewModel when debugging.

My dialoginfo.xaml (simplified):

```
<ContentControl DataContext="{Binding CurrentCP}" Content="{Binding}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="x:Type local:FysiekeContactpersoon">

            <StackPanel Margin="5,5,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Label Content="Person:"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="114" Height="26"  />
                <TextBox x:Name="ContactNaam"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"   TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Naam}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="218" Height="22"/>
               
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="x:Type local:WinkelOfBedrijf">
            <StackPanel Margin="5,5,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Label Content="Corporate:"   HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="114" Height="26" />
                <TextBox x:Name="ContactNaam"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"   TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Naam}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="218" Height="22"/>
                
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
```

and my dialoginfo.xaml.cs

```
public partial class DialogInfo : Window
{
    ContactPersoonViewModel _viewModel = null;
    public ContactPersoonViewModel ViewModel { get => _viewModel; set => _viewModel = value; }
    


    public DialogInfo(ContactPersoonViewModel vm)
    {
        ViewModel = vm;
        InitializeComponent();
         DataContext = vm.CurrentCP;
   
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? I was through a lot of similar threads, mostly pointing at this solution as correct and the simplest one, comparing with DataTemplateSelector or Property setters and triggers (which also aren't working with me- I've tried :().

Moreover, I have each second time a compilation fail "The key had already been added" of something, but the next compilation is perfectly succeeded after no code has been changed at all(WTF??!).Needless to say, how disappointed I am in XAML. I would appreciate some help in the form of a piece of a suitable code, or a very good tutorial link.

Comment: Maybe `DataContext = vm.CurrentCP` replace with `DataContext = vm`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code should basically work. The only problem I found is you type declaration on the `DataTemplate`.

For properties of type `Type` like `Style.TargetType` the XAML engine will convert the string representation of a type to an actual `Type` instance.
But this is not the case for properties like `DataTemplate.DataType`. Since `DataTemplate` defines the property `DataType` of type `object`, there will be no internal conversion from `string` to `Type`.

This is because `DataTemplate.DataType` expects a `string` for XML types and `Type` for objects.

Because you assigned a `string` to `DataTemplate.DataType`, no object type is resolved, as the data object is expected to be a XML object.

Using `x:Type` in order to define a `Type` rather than a `string` is correct, but you simply forgot to mark the declaration as markup extension using *curly braces*! Without this braces you are just defining a `string` value.
The correct syntax is:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FysiekeContactpersoon}">
  ...
</DataTemplate>
```